# Очень медленно работает.Headless Chrome

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Всем доброго.
В коде ниже мои настройки Headless браузера Canary.Вот в такой связке:Python+selenium+Headless Chrome Работает медленнее обычного Хрома раз в пять! Почему, не понятно( Может, кто сталкивался?

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.binary_location = 'C:\\Users\\.....\\chrome.exe'
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\AFT-SITE....\\chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: а зачем вы два раза пишите ```chrome_options = Options()```?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы не задумываетесь о смысле опций которые вы используетесь, то они:

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
```

вам не нужны.

Что-бы на Windows запустить Chrome в Headless достаточно:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.binary_location = 'C:\\Users\\.....\\chrome.exe'
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\AFT-SITE....\\chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

И кстати, IDLE возможно сообщит вам, что `chrome_options=` в объявдении браузера Chrome в `driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=)`, немножно устарело, и сейчас нужно писать просто `options=`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
Сейчас это скорее всего никак не повлияет на код, но в будущем возможно код перестанет работать, если в chromedriver уберут перенаправление.

Comment: И без этих аргументов ОЧЕНЬ медленно переходит по ссылке.

Comment: И, если писать просто options= валится в ошибку Инвалид синтаксис

Comment: @Сергей Богданов На счёт chrome_option зависит от того, какой chromedriver вы используете, новый (2.45) уже говорит об этом, и кстати, попробуйте и вы обновить chromedriver, может будет лучше

Comment: @ AtachiShadow обновил. Сразу падает. с логом selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: session not created: Chrome version must be between 70 and 73
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)

Comment: @Сергей Богданов у вас старый Chrome Canary как я понимаю (младше 70-й версии обычного Chrome), Тогда или вернуть старый chromedriver, или обновить Canary

Comment: @ AtachiShadow Версия Canary Версия 74.0.3688.0 (Официальная сборка), canary (64 бит), а хромдрайвер старый вернул

Comment: @Сергей Богданов, я вот сейчас посмотрел, для Canary используется chromedriver по ссылке http://chromedriver.chromium.org/chromedriver-canary, а не обычный chromedriver, вы его используете?

Comment: @ AtachiShadow Нет, обычный. Сейчас попробую этот. Спасибо)

Comment: @Сергей Богданов напишите, помог ли другой драйвер

Comment: Нет. Просто падает. Вернул старый... Все по прежнему( ищу